# What does the phrase "uncoupled across coordinate directions" mean in this text?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

The following paragraph is from a paper about comparison of maneuvering target tracking models.In the paragraph it talks about constant acceleration models.

> The above models are simple but crude. Actual
>   maneuvers seldom have (nearly) constant accelerations
>   that are uncoupled across coordinate directions.

What doest it mean to say that constant acceleration model is coordinate uncoupled under certain circumstances?
Thanks for your help.